# subdocument with different schemas

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to Mongoose and I'm trying to understand how to properly declare structures.

Say, I have a single collection `todos` that should contain documents describing what should be done. All TODO items have some properties in common, but most details depend on the specific task.

```
// Tasks:

var hairCutSchema = new Schema({
  style: {type: String, required:true},
  length: Number
});

var paintWallSchema = new Schema({
  color: {type: String, required:true},
  surface: Number, required:true},
  layers: Number
});

let napSchema = new Schema({
  duration: {type: Number, required:true},
  dream: String,
  pillows: Number,
  // ....
});


// TODOs (parent document):

var todoSchema = new Schema({
  due: Date,
  created: Date,
  task: <either hairCutSchema, paintWallSchema OR napSchema>
});
```

Of course this isn't really valid code, but I hope it makes my problem clear:

Each todo item should contain exactly *one* task. There is a limited, well known list of *possible* tasks and each of them has *very specific properties*/schema (in my application these subdocuments would be way more complicated).

AFAIK this can't be solved using [subdocuments] because I can only assign *one* subdocument type per field. Any I need exactly one subdocument anyway, not a list.

An alternative might be something like this:

```
var todoSchema = new Schema({
  due: Date,
  created: Date,

  hairCutTask: haitCutSchema,
  paintWallTask: paintWallSchema,
  napTask: napSchema
});
```

However, this way the schema won't prevent me to declare `hairCutTask` and `napTask` at the same time - and probably the required subdocument fields would make *each* of the three types required anyway.

---

What is a good way to structure such data and how should the schema look like?

Comment: "AFAIK this can't be solved using [subdocuments] because I can only assign one subdocument type per field." -- you can look into Schema.Types.Mixed for this (not as useful as creating an actual reference to a collection item)

Comment: Such a "mixed" schema type would not stop me from storing something senseless, not matching any of the task schemas, right?

Answer (score 2):

"discriminators" are probably what I'm looking for: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html